# Disallow changing boot option and bash-like command line in grub

Tags: linux, boot, grub2

I'm using Arch Linux and in my home, I share my computer to others. They have physical access to my computer and I don't want them changing how GRUB boot into Linux by pressing e or have a command line by pressing c. Is there any way to block them from changing or having a command line in grub? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Note that although a grub password makes it harder to mess with stuff, anyone with unrestricted physical access can gain full control over your computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Is there any way to block them from changing or having a command line in grub?

You can set and then encrypt a grub password:

> **Use grub password command in `grub.conf`**
>
> `/boot/grub/grub.conf` contains information about the entries that are
> displayed in the GRUB menu during system startup. On some systems,
> `/etc/grub.conf` is a symbolic link to `/boot/grub/grub.conf`
>
> Add the following `password` line to the `grub.conf` file.
>
> ```
> $ cat /etc/grub.conf
> default=0
> timeout=15
> password GrbPwd4SysAd$
> ..
> ```
>
> Once the `password` command is added to the `grub.conf`, the following
> message will be displayed right under the GRUB menu during the system
> startup.
>
> ```
> Use the up-arrow and down-arrow keys to select which entry is highlighted. 
> Press enter to boot the selected OS or
> 'p' to enter a password to unlock the next set of features.
> ```

You should then encrypt the grub password:

> **Encrypt the grub password using grub-crypt**
>
> `grub-crypt` will get the clear text password from the user, and display
> the encrypted password as shown below.
>
> ```
> # grub-crypt
> Password: GrbPwd4SysAd$
> Retype password: GrbPwd4SysAd$
> ^9^32kwzzX./3WISQ0C
> ```
>
> Modify the `grub.conf` file, add the `password` entry with the
> `–encrypted` argument as shown below. Just copy the output of the
> `grub-crypt` command, and paste it after the `–encrypted` argument in
> the password entry.
>
> ```
> $ cat /etc/grub.conf
> default=0
> timeout=15
> password --encrypted ^9^32kwzzX./3WISQ0C
> ```
>
> ..
>
> By default, the `grub-crypt` command encrypts the password using SHA-512
> algorithm. You can also encrypt the password either using SHA-256 or
> MD5 algorithms as shown below.
>
> ```
> # grub-crypt --sha-256
> # grub-crypt --md5
> ```
>
> You can also use `md5crypt` to encrypt the password. In that case, you
> should use `password –md5 encrypted-password` in your `grub.conf`
> file.

Source: [How to Password Protect Grub Boot Loader in Linux](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/09/grub-password-command/)

---

#### What if I'm using `grub2`?

> **Generate GRUB Bootloader Password**
>
> Create a password for GRUB, be a root user, and open the command
> prompt, type the below command.
>
> ```
> # grub2-setpassword
> ```
>
> When prompted type grub password twice and press enter.
>
> [image]
>
> This will generate a hashed GRUB bootloader password in the file
> `/boot/grub2/user.cfg` file and can be viewed using the `cat` command
> as shown.
>
> ```
> # cat /boot/grub2/user.cfg
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> After creating the GRUB password, you need to re-create the new GRUB
> configuration file by running the following command.
>
> ```
> # grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> The above command will set the grub password in the configuration
> file. Now, reboot the system and check if the new GRUB password is set
> properly.
>
> ```
> # reboot
> ```
>
> **Testing GRUB Password Protection**
>
> After your system restart, you will get the following GRUB screen,
> where you will get 5 seconds to break the normal boot process. So
> quickly press <kbd>e</kbd> to break the boot process.
>
> [image]
>
> Once you press <kbd>e</kbd> it will prompt you to enter the GRUB
> password as shown.
>
> After entering the right username and password, you can edit GRUB
> parameters as shown.
>
> [image]

Source: [How to Set GRUB2 Password in RHEL, CentOS and Fedora Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/password-protect-grub-in-linux/)

Comment: It worked on RHEL, and might work on Arch too. Thanks!